# Creating a media player in Java

Tags: java, media-player

I have taken a Java course at college this semester, and I've to submit a project at the end of the semester. I thought of making a Media Player that can play audio files in Java as my project. Can someone suggest how can I begin, which APIs / libs to use?

I am using Eclipse as the IDE and I have WindowBuilder installed in it.

Comment: Given that it's a homework assignment, I would think that the primary focus is on your ability to put together a complete project, not to have perfect audio quality. A quick Google search should turn up something useful.

Answer (score 0):

VlcJ is java library  which supports almost all media types. 
Download it from  https://code.google.com/p/vlcj/